# Find minimizer of the functional $l(u)= \int_{-1} ^1 u(t) \mathbb d t$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

Find minimizer of the functional 
$ l(u)= \int \limits _{-1} ^1 u(t) \mathbb d t $ with $u(-1)=u(1)=0 $ subject to $g(u)=\int \limits _{-1} ^1 \sqrt{1+u'(t)} \mathbb d t=π $.

I solved it using Lagrange's equations and I found $u(t)=\sqrt{\lambda ^2 -(t+c)^2 }+c$.

First I started by $l^*=l- \lambda g$
then I used the Euler-Lagrange equation ($l_u -\frac{d}{dt}l_u'=0$) or first integral ($l-u'l_u'=c$).

My problem is how to find value of $c$.

Comment: Please correct the very many mistakes in your question first. What are the limits of integration. What do you mean by $u(1)=u(1)$? Who is $\lambda$?

Comment: Sorry they are 1 and -1

Comment: $g(t)$ seems to be a constant?

Comment: Sara, if you do not correct your mistakes nobody will answer. Do you see that $g(t)=\pi \space \forall t$? Is it really what you meant?

Comment: @mickep: I think I understand: both $l$ and $g$ depend on $u$ (since they are functionals), not on $t$. I have edited the original question accordingly.

Comment: There is no mistakes , this qustion i have it from old exam ,and it was like this

Comment: So now how i can find the constant c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the initial conditions $u(-1)=u(1)=0$, just impose $\sqrt {\lambda ^2 - (-1 + c)^2} + c = \sqrt {\lambda ^2 - (1 + c)^2} + c = 0$. The first equality gives $c=0$. Next, using $c=0$, the second equality will give $\lambda = \pm 1$.

Comment: $\lambda$ is probably the Lagrange multiplier of the restriction.

Comment: @themaker: I doubt that she talks about Lagrange's method for constrained extrema; she most probably talks about Euler-Lagrange's equations from the calculus of variations (which makes sense given that we have a functional equation here).

Comment: Yes this true .i update the qustion

Comment: @Alex M. Yes, it is a functional equation, but with a constraint, so you obtain a Lagrange equation with a Lagrange multiplier.